# Wait until an element is active, selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium webdriver 2, I'm faced with the following problem:

I localize an element by

```
find_element_by_link_text("Archive")
```

This is an HTML of the element when *unclicked*:

```
<a onclick="Event.GetDataEvent(226780, 'LH', 19, 19, '', 
'http://www.example.com/');" 
href="javascript:void(0);">Archive</a>
```

When *clicked* it turns into (notice `class="active"`):

```
<a class="active" onclick="Event.GetDataEvent(226780, 'LH', 19, 19, '', 
'http://www.example.com/');" 
href="javascript:void(0);">Archive</a>
```

I want to wait for the element to be `class="active"`. I think the way to go is by using WebDriverWait but how do I actually tell selenium to wait until

`find_element_by_link_text("Archive")` (and no other link_text) has `class="active"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait.until(..)`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait):

> until(method, message='')
>
> Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the
> return value is not False.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

...

def archive_link_is_active(driver):
    cls = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Archive").get_attribute('class')
    return cls and 'active' in cls
 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(archive_link_is_active)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an error though. If you could take a look.  ` Perhaps it's just me using it incorrectly. This is my code: `for arch in driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Archive"):` `arch = arch.click()` `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(archive_link_is_active)` `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300);")` When first arch link in being clicked I got this error `Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM' . Is anything wrong with my code? When I use time.sleep() instead, the code is working as expected.

Comment: @nutship, Sorry but it's hard to read your code in the comment. I made a sample script a few days ago. See [the script](https://gist.github.com/falsetru/6398515) for reference.